# How to handle properly big factorials in Maxima?

Tags: probability, computer-algebra-systems, maxima-software

When I tried to solve a very basic probability problem using Maxima, I stumbled upon the following error: `EXPT: floating point overflow`

I got it when I tried to solve this problem related to Yu-Gi-Oh cards:

> If 20 million cards are manufactured for a box, of which 185185 are "secret rare", then what is the likelihood that after buying 216 cards, none of them will be secret rare.

It has been like 15 years the last time I encountered probability excercises, so I'm not sure if my solution is good, but I tried to solve it the following way:

- All possible ways to draw 216 cards from 20 million: 20000000! / (216! * (20000000 - 216)!)
- There are 20000000 - 185185 = 19814815 cards which are not secret rare
- All possible ways to draw 216 card from the non-secret rare cards: 19814815! / (216! * (19814815 - 216)!)
- So the probability is the ratio of the two: (19814815! / (216! * (19814815 - 216)!)) / (20000000! / (216! * (20000000 - 216)!))

But when I enter this into Maxima, it first simplifies it to:

> (19814815!*19999784!)/(19814599!*20000000!)

When I right-click and select "To Float", then it gives the above mentioned error. Is my solution wrong or something has to be done in Maxima to handle the big factorials?

Comment: Have you tried `bigfloat`? You have to adjust the `fpprec` to be higher than the precision of `float` to get meaningful results. The other option would be to use logarithms, though that will still need extra precision to avoid loss of significance.

Comment: @SeanLake Thank you, it works with big float. It gives 0.134 after some seconds of thinking.

Comment: Let me know how **log_gamma (z)** works for your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To make it much, much, much faster, considering
$$A=\frac {a!\, b!}{c!\, d!}=\frac{\Gamma(a+1)\,\Gamma(b+1)}{\Gamma(c+1)\,\Gamma(d+1)}$$take logarithms of both sides
$$\log(A)=\log (\Gamma (a+1))+\log (\Gamma (b+1))-\log (\Gamma (c+1))-\log (\Gamma (d+1))$$ and use function **log_gamma (z)** in Maxima.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about this method. Strange, it converts it back to log/factorial, instead of using log_gamma. So I still have to use bigfloat. It gives the same answer: `%e ^ -2.00932564586401 = 1.340790608190811b-1`